# How should I get the only the number in float format from the string starting with dollar sign?

Tags: php, string

I've following code:

```
<?php
  $amount = '$40.0';
?>
```

I want to get the number 40 only(in float form) from the string $40 i.e. after excluding the dollar sign. The number entered by user could be even float also like $345.894534. In case of float number, the entire float number I should get except the dollar sign. Also the variable can be empty at a times so the operation of typecasting should perform only when the variable contains some value. How should I do this in optimum way and by making use of ready made functions available in PHP? Can somebody please help me in this regard?Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd recommend a regex. http://regular-expressions.info A little work with `substr` would be fine too. This is so trivial, being "most optimal" hardly matters.

Comment: @MarkBaker:I've corrected my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$amount = floatval(str_replace('$','','$40.2356'));   //0 for empty string
```

Comment: Note that you should not use floats for monetary values.

Comment: @deceze that's true but  OP used the word `float` so many times, I couldn't help it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$amount = '$345.894534';
$trimmed = ltrim($amount, "$"); // will return 345.894534
```